# Is the maximum of the eigenvalues of any symmetric positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix having  dimension $n  \times n \;, \; \; n\geq 2$. If one wants to pick the maximum of its eigenvalues, will the value be positive? Suppose A was an adjacency matrix, should one expect the same results?

Comment: For the first part you should consider $-I$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one wants to pick the maximum of its eigenvalues, will the value be positive?

Of course not. Consider

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For an adjacency matrix, it's true that the largest eigenvalue is non-negative, but that's not trivial; see eg [here](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/eigenvals-x.pdf) or [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/cbms-115-prev.pdf) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63589/the-first-eigenvalue-of-a-graph-what-does-it-reflect).

Update: as A.G. notes in a comment, for a symmetric adjacency matrix (more in general: if all eigenvalues are real) it's actually trivial that the largest eigenvalue is non-negative: because, elsewhere the trace would be negative, which is imposible. By the same observation, restricting to symmetric adjacency matrices distinct from zero, then we can assert that the largest eigenvalue is strictly positive.

Comment: except that the $0$ matrix is also an adjacency matrix and its largest eigenvalue is not positive

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ok, fixed

Comment: At least for *symmetric* adjacency matrices it is trivial: the matrix elements are $\ge 0$, then the trace $\ge 0$ which is the sum of all (real) eigenvalues.

Comment: @A.G. True, I'm adding that

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is simetric and positive you have $(Ax,x)>0$ and if $x$ is an eigenvector you have $(\lambda x,x)>0$. So $\lambda >0$.

Comment: Please do not vote down any of these two answers. They have both given me some insights. Please please please.